# how can i get my case statement to return both prefer action and prefer comedy in my custom preference column if a person has both marked as 1

Tags: mysql, sql, case

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName,

CASE 

WHEN [Action] = '1' THEN 'Prefer Action'

WHEN Comedy = '1' THEN 'Prefer Comedy'

WHEN Drama = '1' THEN 'Prefer Drama'

WHEN Horror = '1' THEN 'Prefer Horror'

WHEN Romance = '1' THEN 'Prefer Romance'
ELSE ' '
END AS 'Customer Preference'

FROM RentalMDB.dbo.Customers
```

Comment: Case statement short circuits, you could just add the combination case to top. Alternatively turn each WHEN into a case and that returns empty string if false and concat the results together. You can just put a trailing space at the end of each true value and rtrim at the end

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below Union statement,

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName,
CASE 
WHEN [Action] = '1' THEN 'Prefer Action'
WHEN Drama = '1' THEN 'Prefer Drama'
WHEN Horror = '1' THEN 'Prefer Horror'
WHEN Romance = '1' THEN 'Prefer Romance'
ELSE ' '
END AS 'Customer Preference'
FROM RentalMDB.dbo.Customers

UNION ALL

SELECT FirstName, LastName,
CASE 
WHEN Comedy = '1' THEN 'Prefer Comedy'
WHEN Drama = '1' THEN 'Prefer Drama'
WHEN Horror = '1' THEN 'Prefer Horror'
WHEN Romance = '1' THEN 'Prefer Romance'
ELSE ' '
END AS 'Customer Preference'
FROM RentalMDB.dbo.Customers
```